# Setting Username and Password For Cassandra database

Tags: cassandra

I am Very much new to cassandra database. I need to set up a username and password for the database ... Somebody please help me explaining how to do that..

Answer (score 6):

You can create users with passwords that have ro or rw access at the column family level.  For Cassandra 0.7 or earlier, you can find an overview here: http://www.datastax.com/docs/0.7/configuration/authentication

For 1.0 and later, authentication was moved into the examples directory.  You can find an example of how to configure it (same as before) here: http://devblog.michalski.im/2012/04/05/adding-simple-authentication-to-cassandra/

In general, Cassandra developers seem to recommend segregating your Cassandra database via firewall over relying on user/pass authentication.  If you can go this route, it's much preferred.

For additional security, you can also encrypt inter-node communication: http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/InternodeEncryption

Comment: The SimpleAuthenticator and SimpleAuthority classes were moved to the examples directory because they are not intended to be used in production. From NEWS.txt: "They never provided actual security and in their current state are only meant as examples."

Comment: once you have the users set up, how do you login to one of them? Or execute queries/commands as one of them?

Comment: @Pinocchio look at the last couple lines of http://devblog.michalski.im/2012/04/05/adding-simple-authentication-to-cassandra/ for your answer

Answer (score 2):

Here's some more on Cassandra's permissions too (after you setup authentication): 
http://devblog.michalski.im/2012/04/22/more-on-cassandra-simpleauthority-permissions/

So, there's a bit more than only the CF-level permission system.